# How to insert a value whose column type is 'character' in foxpro dbf file .?

Tags: ado, foxpro

I am programming in  MFC and using ADO to connect to a FoxPro .dbf file .I am reading file and making a copy of the database file  .While inserting a data  whose column type is 'C' i.e Character (though its length is 10 byte.value being "0002      ") i am having problem. "0" is being inserted in the field.I can  change the Column type from 'Character' to 'Memo' that inserts the right value but keeps data away in .FPT file.I need to insert data in same .dbf file .Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show your insert statement? Also, what does the value look like that you are inserting? If the column is only 10 characters and the value has more than 10 leading spaces, perhaps this is the problem? Try placing the value inside an ALLTRIM() function or make the character column larger, perhaps 200 characters.

Comment: If you're making a straight copy would it not be easier just to use the file system to copy the DBF/CDX/FPT files?

Comment: @jerry .I am using AddNew() function of recordset which takes two argument both being COleSafeArray of field name and data ;

Comment: And trimming does not solve the problem.I think character type is taking only one character.since my value is "0002" it is only taking "0"

Comment: @alan i want to do it programaticaly.

Answer (score 1):

By default, a `C` type column in FoxPro has a length of 1.  If you are using standard SQL commands (`ALTER TABLE`) or SQL-like equilvalents (`CREATE CURSOR`), you need to change a simple "C" data type to "C(10)".

If you are instead creating your data copy using FoxPro's "SELECT INTO" syntax, be aware that the library infers the size of each column based on the first row.  You would want to, in this case, to have "field1" as a C(10), define the column not as a simple `field1' but rather`CAST(field1 as C(10)) as field1`.